# Is it possible to merge two images in one shape with css?

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I have two below images like below.

**Image 1**

[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

I want to merge these two images with **css** and expect like this below image.

**Expected Image**

[image]

Please help me to set images like this.

I tried with clip-path but got nothing:

```css
div {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzeP9.png);
  background-size:contain;
  height:200px;
  clip-path:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkKi6.png)
}
```

```html
<div ></div>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: mask-image. Have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `mask` is made for:

```css
img {
  -webkit-mask:url(https://i.ibb.co/sFjJtNN/PkKi6.png) center/contain no-repeat;
  max-width:100%;
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzeP9.png" >
```